# How can I get the GPS location of the user's device for an API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, geolocation

I am building an **ASP.Net Web API** project. And I need to access the exact device's Geo-location (not via IP address). I have successfully used `Xam.Plugin.Geolocator` for a similar *Xamarin Cocoa* app for Mac OS. But I am still looking for the best method to use for the API project.

Is it possible to use the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` (or equivalent) in the C# code of my **ASP.Net Web API** project?

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is JavaScript, so no, it cannot be used in C# code.

Comment: Your Web API project runs where? So any code executed with-in it will pull data from? You will need to transmit location information from the client to your Web API as parameters...

Comment: The Web API is intended to run on mobile devices. And it should, in theory, return a JSON response based on the Geo-Location. Therefore, I am trying to implement the request for the Geo-Location in the GET method of the controller.

Comment: Why do you have a Web API running on a mobile device?  You cannot get their geolocation data in Web API.  It *must* be done through JS and sent *to* Web API.

Comment: The idea was to develop a very quick concept of a mobile app via Web API because it's easy to develop and test via navigator. But I see what you mean, it is better to turn into a Web app that uses this API by sending it the location.